# Ruby " yield row if block_given?"

Tags: ruby

```
  # Get our data back
  def queryNewsTable
    @conn.exec( "SELECT * FROM newslib" ) do |result|
      result.each do |row|
        yield row if block_given?
      end
    end
  end
```

For this piece of code. I don't quite understand  `yield row if block_given?`

can anybody point to any good article teaching about this or you can briefly explain it to me a little bit
thanks so much

Comment: it's usually good style to provide what happens when a block *isn't* given, as well.. i.e. provide `result.to_enum`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This `yield row if block_given?` means that block which could be passed into the `#queryNewsTable` method(!), is evaluated with [yield](/questions/tagged/yield) operator, in other words, if you pass the block into function `#queryNewsTable`:

```
queryNewsTable do 
   #some code
end
```

You will get the call to the code, for each of rows in the `result` variable.

NOTE: That for your case it will be better to optimize the code (if not [db](/questions/tagged/db)[trigger](/questions/tagged/trigger) is used):

```
# Get our data back
def queryNewsTable
  @conn.exec( "SELECT * FROM newslib" ) do |result|
    result.each do |row|
      yield row
    end
  end if block_given?
end
```

Comment: thanks @Малъ Скрылевъ, about your optimization proposal, what's the purpose of that?

Comment: @NoName because code the function as it is, has no sense, when no block is passed, so when it is, we just exists out of proc.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ `@conn.exec` might have a return value that the caller of `queryNewsTable` expects to receive regardless of whether a block is passed.

Comment: @AntonKhamets and it will return it)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ If `block_given?` is false, `@conn.exec` won't be executed, making function's return value nil.

Comment: @AntonKhamets yes, if there is no block, select result doesnt matter

Comment: because yielding uses each methon, so it says that performance is being processed in the block

Answer (score 5):

Ask yourself how `Hash.new` works:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-new

It can take no argument, a single argument, or a block. If there is no argument, fetching the value for a non-existent key gives nil. If there is a block, fetching the value for a non-existent key gives whatever the block says to give. Clearly its implementation needs a way to ask "was there a block?" so that it knows which behavior to use. That is what `block_given?` does.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-block_given-3F

As for `yield`, it is simply the way a method that has taken a block *calls* the block, passing it parameters as needed.

Answer (score 2):

When you use functions like `Enumerable#each`, you typically pass in a block using `{|arg| ... }` or `do ... end`. The line `yield row if block_given?` checks to see if a block was supplied to this function call, and if it was, calls that block with `row` as an argument.

One way you might use this function would be:

```
queryNewsTable {|row| puts row}
```

This example would print each row of the query to standard output, since the block that does the printing gets called for each row in the query result. If no block were given, then that line would be ignored.